# Matlab: How do I call a function which I have defined within a class?

Tags: matlab, oop

I'm trying to learn how to use classes in Matlab, having never used them in any language before, so apologies if this is a bit basic.

I have defined a class called `car`, with the properties of colour, type, serial number and speed, with a function to change the speed.

```
classdef car <handle
   properties
      colour
      type
      speed
   end 
   properties (SetAccess = private)
      SerialNumber
   end
   methods
       function faster(obj, v)
           obj.speed = obj.speed + v;
       end
   end
end
```

In another script I can type

`car.colour = "red"`, and when I `disp(car)`, the class has the property colour with label "red". When I call `faster(100)` however, instead of setting `car.speed=100`, it throws the error

```
Check for missing argument or incorrect argument data type in call to function 'faster'.
```

I built the class and method using the same sort of code structure as in this question:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/395472-how-to-call-a-method-from-a-class-called-a-within-another-method-from-a

where the user seemed to not have the issue I do. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong - my function seems like it should work. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please don’t learn to program from random examples of uncertain provenance or by asking questions on SO. Instead, buy a book, or read the fantastic documentation that MATLAB has: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/object-oriented-programming.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the function on the class

```
myCar = car();
myCar.faster( 10 ); % equivalent to 'faster( myCar, 10 )'
```

If you hadn't specified the `< handle` type, you would also need to assign it back to the class, i.e.

```
myCar = myCar.faster( 10 );
```

But you don't need this with a `handle` class.

Comment: `myCar.faster(10)` is the same as `faster(myCar,10)`, but the latter I think is more natural, especially when dealing with non-handle classes.

Comment: @Cris `faster( myCar, 10 )` is also more natural once you start overloading functions, such that the syntax remains the same. Although I think the dot notation makes it more explicit at first glance that the `faster` function (in this case) is implemented within that class (or package).

Comment: That I agree with.